# Re: Dry Gas (specifically STP Water Remover)

Tags: fuel-system, gasoline

Well, it's butt cold here in Maine & my car wouldn't start. It has a 1/4 tank of gas & I was unable to add 1/2 bottle of dry gas as it comes out very fast. So despite the directions on the bottle saying to add a whole thing of dry gas to AT LEAST a 1/2 tank of gas, I now have most of a bottle in 1/4 tank. What is going to happen now? Anything? What should I do next? Any input is appreciated! Thank you! ~ Mechanically Spastic & Freezing in Maine

Comment: a double dose of dry gas wont hurt anything. They just don't want you pouring it into an almost empty tank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fuel dryer products usually contain anhydrous (dewatered) ethyl alcohol. This absorbs water from gasoline and the air. No damage will be done as modern fuel systems are designed to handle ethanol. If you are concerned about long term effects of this slight over-concentration make one trip the the filling station and fill the tank. If this was my car would not be concerned and drive as usual.

If a significant amount of water is suspected to be in the tank several treatments will be needed as each bottle of drier only absorbs a few ounces of water.

Water in fuel is not common any more as the ethanol in E-10 usually holds any water in suspension throughout the delivery system.

Alcohols can be a problem in fuel systems in cars built before the the 1980's as the elastomers in the fuel delivery system can be damaged.